# Error connecting to local MySQL instance from Google App Engine Java.

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I have created a google app engine java project using the gradle build plugin. The app engine version is 1.9.34.  I am trying to connect local dev server to local mysql db for development and testing purposes. I am trying to connect local db as follows,

```
 try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDB?user=root";

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin123$");

        String statement = "INSERT INTO entries (firstName, lastName, phoneNo, email) VALUES( ? , ? , ?, ?)";
        java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(statement);
        stmt.setString(1, newContact.getFirstName());
        stmt.setString(2, newContact.getLastName());
        stmt.setString(3, newContact.getPhoneNumber());
        stmt.setString(4, newContact.getEmail());
        int success = 2;
        success = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (success == 1) {

            System.out.println("Insert Successful");
        } else if (success == 0) {
            System.out.println("Insert error");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But keep getting the following error,

> SEVERE: exception occurred while calling backend method
>       java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:65)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>       at com.aarnam.whatsthescore.apis.AddressBookApi.createNewContact(AddressBookApi.java:67)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
>       at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:513)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
>       at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
>       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:454)
>       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
>       at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
>       at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
>       at java.lang.Thread.(Thread.java:445)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.(Timer.java:499)
>       at java.util.Timer.(Timer.java:101)
>       at java.util.Timer.(Timer.java:146)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:208)
>       ... 53 more

Have been stuck at this since last few days. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below dependency in your app engine gradle ?

```
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
```

If yes, you can also check to change the version of app engine to 1.9.18, it works with me, I had issues in past with version 1.9.22 and later ones.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have enabled MySQL Connector/J in `appengine-web.xml` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Then use something like the below code snippet to connect to the database.

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    url = "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/your-database?user=root";
} else {
    // Local MySQL instance to use during development.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/your-database?user=root";

    // Alternatively, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
    // jdbc:mysql://ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance:3306/your-database?user=root
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have tried both of the options suggested above. Both the changes are necessary to get the app working but the issue in my case was the mysql connector version. I was using 5.1.16 but then I updated it to 5.1.38 and that fixed the problem.

Thank you all for your help and suggestions! :)